# Can't find eReader_android_1.0.39.apk file to install to emulator

Tags: android

Looking to replace a ZIRE31 Palm device I need a PalmReader equivalent for Android. Not having a new device yet (although thinking about the Archos43 model) I am running developer.android.com's SDK which has an emulator in it. Using the emulator I would like to try out ereader.com's application called "eReader_android_1.0.39.apk" from their site. But the download link they supply is actually a ZIP file with lots of little files. I need the simpler APK file to install with the 'adb' command. Does anyone know where I can find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bought a SmartQ V5-II ($130 + $30 shipping from ALLPMP) in early December. It has Linux and Android OS's on it. I have concentrated my development on the Linux OS and have no need to try out the eReader_android_1.0.39.apk application anymore. Under Linux I found the V5-II has the FBReader application which supports the reading of e-books in the EPUB format as well as many others. I have learned enough about EPUB format to convert the text file I wish to read on my V5-II into EPUB. Problem solved!